# How do i show only 1 post from latest 10 post?

Tags: wordpress

my english language is not good. sorry!

this code is for checkbox in advanced custom field plugin.

i want show only 1 post(randomly) from latest 10 post.

please help me. thanks

('posts_per_page' => 10) and ('numberposts' => 10) is not working.

```
<?php
$gallery = array(
"offset" => "0",
'showposts' => '1',
'orderby'        => 'rand',
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'postcat',
'value' => '"selection"',
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)));
// query
$qgallery = new WP_Query( $gallery );
?>  
<?php if( $qgallery->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while( $qgallery->have_posts() ) : $qgallery->the_post(); ?>
<div class="fromgallery">
<a href="0" class="frgall">
<span class="frgdesc"><?php the_title() ?></span>
</a></div>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$gallery = array(
'post_type'             => 'post',
'posts_per_page'        => 10,
'order'                 => 'DESC',
'no_found_rows'         => 'true',
'_shuffle_and_pick'     => 1
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'postcat',
'value' => '"selection"',
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)));
$qgallery = new \WP_Query( $gallery );
```

I only do change in your code. For randomly one post you need to use '_shuffle_and_pick' => 1 , 'posts_per_page' => 10 is from 10 post and 'order' => 'DESC' is for latest posts. for custom '_shuffle_and_pick' you need to add

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts, \WP_Query $qgallery )
{
    if( $pick = $qgallery->get( '_shuffle_and_pick' ) )
    {
        shuffle( $posts );
        $posts = array_slice( $posts, 0, (int) $pick );
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: _shuffle_and_pick must be called from somewhere. Isn't that so?

Answer (score 1):

To show Random post , Please use below script:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      =>  'post',
    'posts_per_page'        => 10,
    'orderby'               => 'date',
    'order'                 => 'DESC',
    'no_found_rows'         => 'true',
    '_shuffle_and_pick'     => 1
    'post_status'           =>  'publish',
    'meta_query'            => array(
                         array(
                           'key' => 'postcat',
                           'value' => '"selection"',
                           'compare' => 'LIKE'
                         )
                   )
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
//check is post found 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo  get_the_title(); 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks but i want get 1 random posts from 10 latest.

Comment: @ramin, it will give 1 post among 10 latest post. To pick 1 post we use key _shuffle_and_pick => 1